# How can I perform this left join in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following two models in django that represent a post and the post's likes:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=200)
    content = TextField()
    num_comments = PositiveIntegerField(default=0)



class Like(models.Model):
    LIKE_CHOICES = [('L', 'Like'), ('D', 'Dislike')]

    user = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = CharField(default='L', max_length=1, choices=LIKE_CHOICES)
    created_at = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

How can I perform a join in my view that would get all the posts and then perform a join to get the like state of the user sending sending the request for each of the posts (None if user hasn't liked or disliked)?

The only way I can think to maybe do this would be to use `select_related()` but I don't know how I would use it in my case since `Post` doesn't have a reference to `Like`.

Comment: I am not sure if i got you correct but can't you do this by just prefetch_related

Post.objects.all().prefetch_related('like__set')

Comment: Post actually have does have a reference with like model in like model where you define a foreign key to post that can also accept a related_name 
default it is like your model with __set

Comment: @amitbisht How would this get the user's like state?

Comment: if you try this line   Post.objects.all().prefetch_related('like__set')  it willl get all post with their associate like model 

if you want filter for a particular user you can do this 

Post.objects.filter(like__set_user_id=userid).prefetch_related('like__set')

Comment: I'm getting an error from you answer: Related Field got invalid lookup: set_user_id

Comment: I dont understand what you're saying

Comment: just do one thing in your model

     post = ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  related_name='post') use this line


and then use this query

Post.objects.filter(post__user_id=userid).prefetch_related('post')

Comment: The result queryset doesn't have the like state. Also this doesnt do what I want. Like I mentioned before I want it to get ALL posts, not just the ones the user liked/disliked

Comment: After getting post do this: `post = Post.objects.get(pk=id)`, `userstate = post.like_set.get(user=User.objects.get(pk=user_id)).state`